# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'modal'

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I got an issues with a JS function :

```
function wcmpMarkeAsShip(self, order_id) {
    JQuery('#wcmp-marke-ship-order-id').val(order_id);
    JQuery('#marke-as-ship-modal').modal('show');
}
```

I have tried to change this function into :

```
function wcmpMarkeAsShip(self, order_id) {
    $('#wcmp-marke-ship-order-id').val(order_id);
    $('#marke-as-ship-modal').modal('show');
}
```

And tried to replace " show " by " toggle " , but I got the same issues :

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'modal'

Thanks you in advance for your help.